# I want to use the android videoView component to play the encrypted m3u8 online video

Tags: android, android-videoview, m3u8

I want to use the android videoView component to play the encrypted m3u8 online video. This m3u8 is encrypted, but you can get key. How can I make this m3u8 play normally on videoview.

This is the m3u8 file address that points to another link:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=720x406
/ppvod/E9E67568FEC5A573D1D935F3CC7DDE9C.m3u8
```

This is the obtained m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:14
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://444.leekemx.com/20180114/1T2COfvy/800kb/hls/key.key"
#EXTINF:10.383,
http://444.leekemx.com/20180114/1T2COfvy/800kb/hls/DAXUDjFV6666000.jpg
#EXTINF:5.004,
xxxxxxx...
```

This is key:

```
9d68b45caee8ac9d
```

Can you give me a rough idea?

Comment: Do you know how the video is encrypted?

Comment: The encryption method is stated clearly in the manifest.

Comment: Anyone found any solution for this?